# Customize Cells/ListView on Xamarin.Forms via Custom Render

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a native(Xamarin.Forms) listview. My data context have 3 property,like :

```
public class MyDataContext :
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string ImageName {get;set;}
  public bool isAvailable {get;set;}
}
```

Where ***Name*** is a property for *textLabel* , ***ImageName*** imagesource for ImageControl and ***isAvailable*** some kind a condition for the cell(true - cell is active,other wise *Cell* have another opacity/background and is not **clickable**,also will appear an image(in right corner)that will show image "***locked***" !).

My listview at current moment :

```
 public class MyListView: ListView
        {
            public MyListView()
            {
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(()=>
                {
                    BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#f2f0e9");
                        var _Label = new Label() { FontSize = 13, TextColor = Color.FromHex("#979797")};
                    _Label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty,"Name");

                    RowHeight = 69;

                     var _Img = new Image(){ WidthRequest = 35, HeightRequest = 42};
                    _Img.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty,"ImageName");

                        return new ViewCell 
                        {
                            View = new StackLayout
                                {
                                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                                    Padding = 10,
                                    Children = 
                                        {
                                            _Img,
                                            new StackLayout
                                            {
                                                Padding = 10,
                                                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                                                Spacing = 0,
                                                Children = 
                                                    {
                                                       _Label,
                                                    }
                                                }
                                        }
                                    }
                        };

                });
            }
        }
    }
```

For some reason i need to customize (both platforms iOs/Android) :

- Divider of cell(need to implement some custom color and size,like on picture) [image]
- Cells disabling(similiar to property isEnabled) with another opacity/background of cell(and her controls label/image etc) :[image]

How i can achieve that?
Any help will be appreciated,thanks!
PS Sorry for my eng. skills!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to write a custom renderer for this unfortunately. In order to set the seperator line the full width of the screen, you will need to set the seperator inset to be zero as shown below.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ListView), typeof(MyListViewRenderer))]
namespace myApp.iOS.Custom_Renderers
{
    public class MyListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var table = (UITableView)this.Control;
            table.SeperatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
        }
    }
}
```

Apologies if any of the syntax above is incorrect, I'm writing from memory but it should set you off on the correct path.

Comment: That is obviously just for the iOS version.

Comment: Unfortunately  did not helped me this trick. This snippet just hided separator.